# Make UIView and views inside of it dim on tap like UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view with an image and a label inside of it. The background is transparent. I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it so you can click it and do an action like clicking on a button. Is there a way to make that view dim gray the way a `UIButton` does when you tap it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override the various `touchesXXX` methods to adjust the colors as desired.

Inside your custom view class, add the following:

```
func dim() {
    // Dim the colors as desired
    imageView.tintColor = .gray
    label.textColor = .darkGray
}

func undim() {
    // Restore the original colors
    imageView.tintColor = .systemBlue
    label.textColor = .black
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    dim()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

    undim()
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)

    undim()
}
```

If your image view is showing a photo instead of an icon, then you might need to do more than just set the image view's `tintColor`.

The above code will not interfere with any `UITapGestureRecognizer` you may have in place.

Note that if you do a simple tap, you won't notice any dimming because it happens too quickly. To see the dimming you need to touch, hold, and then release. And the hold will likely be long enough that the tap gesture won't be recognized because at that point it isn't quick enough to be a tap gesture.